# capture an image using c sharp

Tags: c#, dynamic

I have designed a c sharp application which captures an image using the laptop camera,save it ,and sends a copy via an email with the help of Dynamsoft Dynamic .NET TWAIN 5.3 Trial .... when I run the program from the visual studio it works fine,but when I copy and paste the .exe file outside the program directory it does not work and a message saying "program_name has stopped working "appears.and that is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Dynamsoft.DotNet.TWAIN.Enums;
using Dynamsoft.DotNet.TWAIN.WebCamera;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;

namespace captureImageOfMyLaptopUser
{

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string receiverId;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dynamicDotNetTwain1.IfShowUI = true;
        dynamicDotNetTwain1.SupportedDeviceType = EnumSupportedDeviceType.SDT_WEBCAM;
        dynamicDotNetTwain1.IfThrowException = true;
        if (!Directory.Exists("d:\\WhoOpenedMyLaptop\\Images"))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory("d:\\WhoOpenedMyLaptop");
        }
        string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"d:\WhoOpenedMyLaptop");
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
        int num=0;
        foreach (string path in filePaths)
        {

            int l = path.Length;

             num = int.Parse(path.Substring(24, l - 28));
            list.Add(num);

        }
        int[] array = list.ToArray(typeof(int)) as int[];
        if (array.Length > 0)
        {
            num = array.Max();
        }
        else
        { 
        num=0;
        }

        string fileName = "d:\\WhoOpenedMyLaptop\\pic" + (num + 1).ToString() + ".pdf";
        turnOnCamera();
        captureImage();
        saveImage(fileName);
        sendingTheImage(fileName);
    }
    private void captureImage()
    {
        try
        {
            dynamicDotNetTwain1.EnableSource();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("error");
        }
    }
    private void turnOnCamera()
    {
        try
        {
            dynamicDotNetTwain1.SelectSourceByIndex(0) ;
            dynamicDotNetTwain1.SetVideoContainer(pictureBox1);
            dynamicDotNetTwain1.OpenSource();

            int count = dynamicDotNetTwain1.ResolutionForCamList.Count;
            for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)
            {
                string tempHeight = dynamicDotNetTwain1.ResolutionForCamList[j].Height.ToString();
                string tempWidth = dynamicDotNetTwain1.ResolutionForCamList[j].Width.ToString();
                string tempResolution = tempWidth + "X" + tempHeight;
                comboResolution.Items.Insert(j, tempResolution);
                comboResolution.SelectedIndex = 0;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exp.Message);
        }
    }
    private void saveImage(string imagePath)
    {
        SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
        saveFileDialog.FileName = imagePath;
        saveFileDialog.Filter = "pdf files (*.pdf)|*.pdf|All files (*.*)|*.*";

        dynamicDotNetTwain1.SaveAllAsPDF(saveFileDialog.FileName);



    }
    private void sendingTheImage(string path)
    {
        readEmailIdFromTextFile();
        try
        {
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");

            mail.From = new MailAddress("seewhoopenedyourlaptop@gmail.com");

            mail.To.Add(receiverId);
            string date = DateTime.Now.ToString();

            System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment;
            attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(path);
            mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);
            mail.Subject = "لقد قام هذا الشخص بفتح جهازك  ";
            mail.Body = "التوقيت :  " + date;

            SmtpServer.Port = 587;
            SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("seewhoopenedyourlaptop", "mylaptopcamera");
            SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

            SmtpServer.Send(mail);
           // MessageBox.Show("mail Send");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }

    }
    private void readEmailIdFromTextFile()
    {
        String line;
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("C:\\Program Files\\WhoOpenedMyLaptop\\data.txt");
        line = sr.ReadLine();
        receiverId = line;
        sr.Close();

    }

}
```

}

Comment: exe will not run alone ,you have to copy all output folder in which you have placed all dll's

Comment: Yes ,It works now when i put DynamicDotNetTWAIN.dll in the same folder of the .exe file....but how can i force the user to copy this .dll in the same directory of the exe program?

Comment: @Boulis make installer.

Comment: If you insert new references, always remember to get them with the app. Other way after releasing would be to bind the dll files to the exe itself. That would bring it back to a standalone

Comment: The problem is that you need to copy the dll files over along with the exe as you've found out. But to do that automatically then you will need to use an app installer. Use something like NSIS (and **make sure you check out their GUI wizard which makes it possible to do it easily and quickly**)

Comment: ok....the last problem which faces me is that when i run the program , a message saying: "Thank you very much for evaluating Dynamic.Net TWAIN" appears....how can I get ride of that message

Comment: I think this is one of the restriction of using that library, if you want to get ride of that message, you shouldn't use a trail version..

Comment: :D how about buying  Dynamic software?

Comment: I can not buy it now....Is there a free solution ??

Comment: I guess so. Try to search

Comment: @Boulis -- Try this link: http://sourceforge.net/projects/twainforcsharp/

Answer (score 2):

You should copy the executable files together with all dll files since it depends on them. You can go to references and then select all libraries and at the atributes, change to copy always, then cleanup the project and then build the project, do not run, copy all content of the folder to a new location and open the executable file, it should run